# Function doesnt wait download Picture with Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I try to download picture with Alamofire and this image must be append to custom class. But I didnt do that. Image is downloaded with async and i didnt fix this issue. Where is my mistake ?

**Image always return nil**

// MARK: CUSTOM FUNCTION

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class DownloadPhotoWAlamofire {

func download(imageUid:String , completion : @escaping (UIImage) -> ()  )  {
    let url = "\(Config.fileService)file?uid=\(String(describing: imageUid))"
    print("URL \(url)")

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get ).responseImage { response in
        print("Image Response \(response)")

        let image = response.result.value
        completion(image!)

        }
    }
}
```

// MARK : IN VIEWCONTROL

```
guard let objectElement = o as? [String:Any] else {return}
let managerName = objectElement["managerName"] as? String
let managerAvatarUid = objectElement["managerProfilePictureFileUid"] as? String
let assistantsOfDiariesUid = objectElement["assistantsOfDiariesUid"] as? String

var image:UIImage? = nil

if managerAvatarUid != nil {
    DownloadPhotoWAlamofire().download(imageUid: managerAvatarUid!, completion: { (imageD) in
                    image = imageD
                })
     }

 let e = AssistantInviteElement(managerName: managerName!, managerAvatarUid: managerAvatarUid, assistantsOfDiariesUid: assistantsOfDiariesUid!,avatarImage:image)
 self.managerList.append(e)
```

Comment: Do the `let e = ` & `append(e)` where do you `image = imageD`.

Comment: When I put this lines where you say , doesnt appent to managerList

Comment: Yes it will, but it's async, so it will happen only when image is downloaded. You can't manage async like it was sync. Instead of your current code after the `self.manager.append(e)`, create a func, and call it after you do the `self.manager.append(e)` new place.

Comment: Yes you are right. It works properly . Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to :

```
if managerAvatarUid != nil {
    DownloadPhotoWAlamofire().download(imageUid: managerAvatarUid!, completion: { (imageD) in
        let image = imageD
        let e = AssistantInviteElement(managerName: managerName!, managerAvatarUid: managerAvatarUid, assistantsOfDiariesUid: assistantsOfDiariesUid!,avatarImage:image)
        self.managerList.append(e)
    })
}
```

As downloading is asynchronous call and you this line is executing before image is downloaded :

```
let e = AssistantInviteElement(managerName: managerName!, managerAvatarUid: managerAvatarUid, assistantsOfDiariesUid: assistantsOfDiariesUid!,avatarImage:image)
```

at that time image is nil. So call it only when you have image downloaded and it should work.

Also don't unwrap optional with "!", do a if let/ guard let. So change Almofire code to :

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get ).responseImage { response in
    print("Image Response \(response)")
    if let image = response.result.value {
        print("image downloaded: \(image)")
        completion(image)
    } else {
        print("Image is nil")
    }
}
```

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL Great! Make sure about you don't do force unwrapping of a optional, you can save a lot of crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You set the image directly after starting the asynchronous download, when it of course is still `nil`. The point of using a callback as you do in your code is that you only can use a requested resource once the callback gets called; so you should move the code that's using the image into the callback block.